# How to add legend and table with data value into a chart with different lines using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, visualization

I have this data

`TX_growth<-data.frame(year=c(2017,2016, 2015),statewide=c(61, 62,57),black=c(58,58,53),hispanic=c(59,60,55),white=c(65,64,61))`

Until now I have this chart using the following code:

[My chart until now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GBL8.png)
[image]

```
    ggplot() + geom_line(data = TX_growth, aes(x=year, y= statewide), color = "blue", size=1) + 
    geom_line(data = TX_growth, aes(x=year, y= white), color = "red", size=1) + 
    geom_line(data = TX_growth, aes(x=year, y= black), color = "green", size=1) + 
    geom_line(data = TX_growth, aes(x=year, y= hispanic), color = "orange", size=1) + 
    labs(title = "Figure 1: Statewide Percent who Met or Exceeded Progress", 
         subtitle = "Greater percentage means that student subgroup progressed at higher percentage than previous year.", 
         x = "Year", y = "Percentage progress")+ theme_bw() + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2017,2016,2015))
```

I want to add (a) legend showing the name and color of each line and (b) a table below with all values of my dataframe. Something like this:

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8rNp.gif)
[image]
Instead of cities, my chart would have "Statewide", "White", "Black", and "Hispanic". Also, my table would have years (from 2015 to 2017), rather than months. I don't want the seasons or "freezing" line. I just want to add the legend and table like they did it.

Comment: Maybe you should structure your data differently so that you can include `scale_colour_manual()` with the variables you want the colours to be based on, then it will automatically include a legend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Part 1 - Fixing the legend

Concerning the legend, this is not the `ggplot`-way. Convert your data from wide to long, and then map the `what` keys to the colour as an aesthetic mapping.

```
library(tidyverse)
TX_growth %>%
    gather(what, value, -year) %>%
    ggplot() +
        geom_line(aes(x=year, y= value, colour = what), size=1) +
        labs(
            title = "Figure 1: Statewide Percent who Met or Exceeded Progress",
            subtitle = "Greater percentage means that student subgroup progressed at higher percentage than previous year.",
            x = "Year", y = "Percentage progress") +
        theme_bw() +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2017,2016,2015))
```

[image]

### Part 2 - Adding a table

Concerning the table, this seems to be somewhat of a duplicate of [Adding a table of values below the graph in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164675/adding-a-table-of-values-below-the-graph-in-ggplot2).

To summarise from various posts, we can use `egg::ggarrange` to add a table at the bottom; here is a minimal example:

```
library(tidyverse)
gg.plot <- TX_growth %>%
    gather(what, value, -year) %>%
    ggplot() +
        geom_line(aes(x=year, y= value, colour = what), size=1) +
        theme_bw() +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2017,2016,2015))

gg.table <- TX_growth %>%
    gather(what, value, -year) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = year, y = as.factor(what), label = value, colour = what)) +
        geom_text() +
        theme_bw() +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2017,2016,2015)) +
        guides(colour = FALSE) +
        theme_minimal() +
        theme(
            axis.title.y = element_blank())

library(egg)
ggarrange(gg.plot, gg.table, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

All that remains to do is some final figure polishing.

### Part 3 - After some polishing ...

```
library(tidyverse)
gg.plot <- TX_growth %>%
    gather(Group, value, -year) %>%
    ggplot() +
        geom_line(aes(x = year, y = value, colour = Group)) +
        theme_bw() +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2015:2017)

gg.table <- TX_growth %>%
    gather(Group, value, -year) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = year, y = as.factor(Group), label = value, colour = Group)) +
        geom_text() +
        theme_bw() +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2015:2017) +
        scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
        guides(colour = FALSE) +
        theme_minimal() +
        theme(
            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

library(egg)
ggarrange(gg.plot, gg.table, ncol = 1, heights = c(4, 1))
```

[image]