# Is it possible to combine a ggplot legend and table

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to combine a table and ggplot legend so that the legend appears as a column in the table as shown in the image. Sorry if this has been asked before but I haven't been able to find a way to do this.

[image: Desired output]

Edit: attached is code to produce the output below (minus the legend/table combination, which I am trying to produce, as I stitched that together in Powerpoint)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
library(signal)

#dataset for ggplot
full.data <- structure(list(error = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), prob.ed.n = c(0, 0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0.3, 0.7, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.6, 
1, 1, 1, 1), N = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = "data.frame")

#summary table 
summary.table <- structure(list(prob.fr = c("1.62%", "1.35%", "1.09%", "0.81%", "0.54%", "0.27%"), prob.ed.n = c("87.4%", "82.2%", "74.8%", "64.4%", "49.8%", "29.2%"), N = c(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")

#table object to beincluded with ggplot
table <- tableGrob(summary.table %>%
            rename(
              `Prb FR` = prob.fr,
              `Prb ED` = prob.ed.n,
            ), 
          rows = NULL)
#plot
plot <- ggplot(full.data, aes(x = error, y = prob.ed.n, group = N, colour = as.factor(N))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2.45, colour = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.9, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_line(data = full.data %>%
              group_by(N) %>%
              do({
                tibble(error = seq(min(.$error), max(.$error),length.out=100),
                       prob.ed.n = pchip(.$error, .$prob.ed.n, error))
              }),
            size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = full.data$error, breaks = full.data$error, expand = c(0, 0.05)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0.01, 0.01))) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE, nrow = 1)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"),
        legend.direction= "horizontal",
        legend.position=c(0.8,0.05)
)

#arrange plot and grid side-by-side
grid.arrange(plot, table, nrow = 1, widths = c(4,1))
```

Comment: (1) I haven't found a way to do so in a legend, I've often wanted the same thing. My (not-great) workaround has been to craft the columns into a single string per row and show a "simple" legend, but nothing lines up (and is not good-looking). However, you might be able to use `GGally::ggtable` to create the table and `patchwork` to easily patch them together. (2) Lacking that, your question would benefit from being [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3358272). Good luck!

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53753056/how-to-add-legend-and-table-with-data-value-into-a-chart-with-different-lines-us

Comment: @tjebo that is from the "signal" library. I've updated the code to include it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple approach is to use the legend labels themselves as the table.  Here I demonstrate using `knitr::kable` to automatically format the table column widths:

```
library(knitr)
table = summary.table %>%
  rename(`Prb FR` = prob.fr, `Prb ED` = prob.ed.n) %>%
  kable %>%
  gsub('|', ' ', ., fixed = T) %>%
  strsplit('\n') %>%
  trimws
header = table[[1]]
header = paste0(header, '\n', paste0(rep('─', nchar(header)), collapse =''))
table = table[-(1:2)]
table = do.call(rbind, table)[,1]
table = data.frame(N=summary.table$N, lab = table)
  
plot_data = full.data %>%
  group_by(N) %>%
  do({
    tibble(error = seq(min(.$error), max(.$error),length.out=100),
           prob.ed.n = pchip(.$error, .$prob.ed.n, error))
  }) %>%
  left_join(table)

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = error, y = prob.ed.n, group = N, colour = lab)) +
  geom_line() +
  guides(color = guide_legend(header, reverse=TRUE, 
                              label.position = "left", 
                              title.theme = element_text(size=8, family='mono'),
                              label.theme = element_text(size=8, family='mono'))) +
  theme(
    legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = NA),
    legend.spacing.y = unit(0, "pt"),
    legend.key.height = unit(10, "pt"),
    legend.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: I like this one! Thanks for posting.

Comment: This is a great solution that doesn't require separate positioning of the legend key and table. Thanks for posting, I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: my problem in executing this code was: 
`> table = do.call(rbind, table)[,1]

Error in do.call(rbind, table) : second argument must be a list`

Comment: @MathewVickers - can't really debug that here in the comments without a reproducible example.  Try posting it as a new question with an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  Most likely you did not create a data.frame called `table`, so it thinks you are using the function `table` instead

Answer (score 8):

This is an interesting problem. The short answer: Yes, it's possible. But I don't see a way around hard coding the position of table and legend, which is ugly.

The suggestion below requires hard coding in three places. I am using {ggpubr} for the table, and {cowplot} for the stitching.

<strike>Another problem arises from the [legend key spacing for vertical legends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366964/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-spacing-between-legend-items-in-ggplot2). This is still a rather unresolved issue for other keys than polygons, to my knowledge. [The associated GitHub issue is closed](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2844)</strike> The legend spacing is not a problem any more. [Ask teunbrand, and he knows the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70526027/7941188).

Some other relevant comments in the code.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(cowplot)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'cowplot'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggpubr':
#> 
#>     get_legend

full.data <- structure(list(error = c(
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
  5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
  5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
), prob.ed.n = c(
  0, 0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8,
  1, 1, 0, 0, 0.3, 0.7, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 1, 1, 1, 0,
  0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.6,
  1, 1, 1, 1
), N = c(
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
  3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
  6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6
)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = "data.frame")

summary.table <-
  structure(list(
    prob.fr = c("1.62%", "1.35%", "1.09%", "0.81%", "0.54%", "0.27%"),
    prob.ed.n = c("87.4%", "82.2%", "74.8%", "64.4%", "49.8%", "29.2%"),
    N = c(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
  ), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

## Hack 1 - create some space for the new legend
spacer <- paste(rep(" ", 6), collapse = "")
my_table <-
  summary.table %>%
  mutate(N = paste(spacer, N))

p1 <-
  ggplot(full.data, aes(x = error, y = prob.ed.n, group = N, colour = as.factor(N))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2.45, colour = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.9, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_line(
    data = full.data %>%
      group_by(N) %>%
      do({
        tibble(
          error = seq(min(.$error), max(.$error), length.out = 100),
          prob.ed.n = signal::pchip(.$error, .$prob.ed.n, error)
        )
      }),
    size = 1
  ) +
  ## remove the legend labels. You have them in the table already.
  scale_color_brewer(NULL, palette = "Dark2", labels = rep("", length(unique(full.data$N)))) +
  ## remove all the legend specs! I've also removed the not so important reverse scale
  ## I have removed fill and color to make it aesthetically more pleasing
  theme(
    legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = NA),
    ## hack 2 - hard code legend key spacing
    legend.spacing.y = unit(1.8, "pt"),
    legend.background = element_blank()
  ) +
  ## make y spacing work
  guides(color = guide_legend(byrow = TRUE))

## create the plot elements
p_leg <- cowplot::get_legend(p1)
p2 <- ggtexttable(my_table, rows = NULL)
## we don't want the legend twice
p <- p1 + theme(legend.position = "none")

## hack 3 - hard code the plot element positions
ggdraw(p, xlim = c(0, 1.7)) +
  draw_plot(p2, x = .8) +
  draw_plot(p_leg, x = .97, y = 0.975, vjust = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've added the code necessary for a reproducible example. I'm a little new to this, I did not realize that it is possible to output a dataframe as code using dput(). That made producing the example much simpler than I anticipated.  I like your approach, I ended up using something similar although it suffers from the same limitations you mentioned. I'll post it when it's finished.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. It's unfortunate there isn't an easier/automated way to do this, but with a little trial and error this is just fine for my purposes. Thanks.

Comment: This is what I've been using so far, but @dww has provided a solution that circumvents the issue of having to individually position the legend key and table. I've marked that as the accepted answer for now.

Comment: @reidj no worries at all! I wasn't very happy with my solution (although the result looks fine) - therefore the bounty. I feel we have now some great choices to pick from :)

Answer (score 5):

Let's suppose we have the following plot, which is simplified for brevity from the example code and has a vertical legend.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
library(signal)


# Omitted full code, same as in question
# full.data <- structure(...)
# summary.table <- structure(...)
# table <- tableGrob(...)

# Simplified plot
plot <- ggplot(full.data, aes(x = error, y = prob.ed.n, group = N, colour = as.factor(N))) +
  geom_line(data = full.data %>%
              group_by(N) %>%
              do({
                tibble(error = seq(min(.$error), max(.$error),length.out=100),
                       prob.ed.n = pchip(.$error, .$prob.ed.n, error))
              }),
            size = 1) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"))

plot
```

[image]

We can write the following function to place the legend keys into the table. It is a bit unwieldy because gtable and grid code is often not very elegant, but it should do the job. By default, it replaces the last column in the `tableGrob` output with the keys of the first legend.

Note that this only handles vertical legends, not horizontal ones. Also, it is a bit naive in assuming the table and legend fit together in their natural order: it doesn't do any fancy label matching and assumes the order in the table and legend are the same.

```r
library(grid)
library(gtable)

#' @param tableGrob The output of the `gridExtra::tableGrob()` function.
#' @param plot A ggplot2 object with a single, vertical legend
#' @param replace_col An `integer(1)` with the column number in the 
#'   table to replace with keys. Defaults to the last one.
#' @param key_padding The amount of extra space to surround keys with,
#'   as a `grid::unit()` object.
#'
#' @return A modified version of the `tableGrob` argument
add_legend_column <- function(
  tableGrob, 
  plot,
  replace_col = ncol(tableGrob),
  key_padding = unit(5.5, "pt")
) {
  
  # Getting legend keys
  keys <- cowplot::get_legend(plot)
  keys <- keys$grobs[[which(keys$layout$name == "guides")[1]]]
  keys <- gtable_filter(keys, 'label|key')
  idx  <- unique(keys$layout$t)
  keys <- lapply(idx, function(i) {
    x <- keys[i, ]
    # Set justification of keys
    x$vp$x <- unit(0.5, "npc")
    x$vp$justification <- x$vp$valid.just <- c(0.5, 1)
    # Set key padding
    x <- gtable_add_padding(x, key_padding)
    x
  }) 
  if (nrow(table) != length(keys) + 1) {
    stop("Keys don't fit in the table")
  }
  
  # Measure keys
  width  <- max(do.call(unit.c, lapply(keys, grobWidth)))
  width  <- max(width, table$widths[replace_col])
  height <- do.call(unit.c, lapply(keys, grobHeight))
  
  # Delete foreground content of the column to replace
  drop <- table$layout$l == replace_col & table$layout$t != 1
  drop <- drop & endsWith(table$layout$name, "-fg")
  table$grobs  <- table$grobs[!drop]
  table$layout <- table$layout[!drop, ]
  
  # Add keys to table
  table <- gtable_add_grob(
    table, keys, name = "key",
    t = seq_along(keys) + 1, 
    l = replace_col
  )
  
  # Set dimensions
  table$widths[replace_col] <- width
  table$heights[-1] <- unit.pmax(table$heights[-1], height)
  
  return(table)
}
```

Lastly, we can add the table in our favorite plot composition package as follows. Note that the text size of the legend and the table mismatched, so I've set the legend text size to match the one of the table. Naturally, the plot looks better after you delete the legend that we capture in the table.

```r
library(patchwork)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'patchwork'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:formattable':
#> 
#>     area

(plot + theme(legend.position = "none")) + 
  add_legend_column(table, plot + theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12)))
```

[image]

I have no idea how well this generalises when the plot has > 1 legend or when the `tableGrob()` has additional options turned on or off, it is the first time I've used this function.

Comment: No problem, I'm not greedy for points :)

Answer (score 4):

My solution is not quite what you're looking for, but conveys the information and would be much easier to produce and to cope with graphs of differing numbers of lines.  I've coloured the boxes with the colours from the lines, rather than adding a coloured line.

[image]

NB: Legend kept to show the match between line colours and filled boxes.

The full code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
library(signal)

#dataset for ggplot
full.data <- structure(list(error = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                                      5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                                      5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), prob.ed.n = c(0, 0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 
                                                                                1, 1, 0, 0, 0.3, 0.7, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                                                                                0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.6, 
                                                                                1, 1, 1, 1), N = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                                                                                                   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
                                                                                                   6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = "data.frame")

#summary table 
summary.table <- structure(list(prob.fr = c("1.62%", "1.35%", "1.09%", "0.81%", "0.54%", "0.27%"), 
                                prob.ed.n = c("87.4%", "82.2%", "74.8%", "64.4%", "49.8%", "29.2%"), 
                              N = c(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA,-6L), class = "data.frame")

# table object to beincluded with ggplot
  table <- tableGrob(summary.table %>%
                       rename(
                         `Prb FR` = prob.fr,
                         `Prb ED` = prob.ed.n,
                       ), rows = NULL)

# Change cells to match the line colours
  # Id the colour codes
    color_range <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(8, "Dark2") # Find the colours being used in the graph 
  
  # Function to find the cell in a tableGrob
    find_cell <- function(table, row, col, name="core-fg"){
      l <- table$layout
      which(l$t==row & l$l==col & l$name==name)
    }
  
  # Fill the cells with the appropriate colour
    for(i in 1:nrow(summary.table)) {
      cell_ref <- find_cell(table, i+1, 3, "core-bg")
      table$grobs[cell_ref][[1]][["gp"]] <- grid::gpar(fill=color_range[nrow(summary.table)+1-i], col = color_range[nrow(summary.table)+1-i], lwd=5)
    }


#plot
plot <- ggplot(full.data, aes(x = error, y = prob.ed.n, group = N, colour = as.factor(N))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2.45, colour = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.9, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_line(data = full.data %>%
              group_by(N) %>%
              do({
                tibble(error = seq(min(.$error), max(.$error),length.out=100),
                       prob.ed.n = pchip(.$error, .$prob.ed.n, error))
              }),
            size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = full.data$error, breaks = full.data$error, expand = c(0, 0.05)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0.01, 0.01))) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE, nrow = 1)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"),
        legend.direction= "horizontal",
        legend.position=c(0.8,0.05)
  )

#arrange plot and grid side-by-side
 grid.arrange(plot, table, nrow = 1, widths = c(4,1))
```

Comment: that's another nice option indeed - why did you choose `brewer.pal(8,...)`? I would think "6" would be more like it? Would it not be safer to chose a programmatic approach, e.g. `length(unique(full.data$N))`?

Comment: This was to extract al the colours from the palette, though 6 or a variable approach is just as valid.

Comment: One other thought, for those *au fait* with `grid`, it should be possible to add coloured lines to the table grob.  There is an example in the help page, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html

Answer (score 3):

I suggest defining the plot and table seperately and then stitching them together. To get colors for the table, you could extract the scale_color_brewer values from the ggplot object and dynamically define your table theme. To stitch, use your favorite multiplot graphics tool, like `gridExtra::grid.arrange()`.

The difference between this answer and the above answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70581378/7941188) is I'm extracting the scale colors directly from the ggplot object to define the colors in the accompanying table. This makes sure the colors are matched up, and theoretically you could use this approach with multiple scales/legends.

Do you want the typical ggplot legend keys? Or is coloring the background of a cell sufficient? EDIT: I updated my answer to show how you could use unicode symbols to approximate ggplot legend keys.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(signal)

ldata <- full.data %>%
  group_by(N) %>%
  do({
    tibble(error = seq(min(.$error), max(.$error),length.out=100),
           prob.ed.n = pchip(.$error, .$prob.ed.n, error))
  })

#plot
p <- ggplot(full.data, aes(x = error, y = prob.ed.n, group = N, colour = as.factor(N))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2.45, colour = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.9, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_line(data = ldata, size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = full.data$error, breaks = full.data$error, expand = c(0, 0.05)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0.01, 0.01))) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

# Get scale data from ggplot object
pb <- ggplot_build(p)
scale_cols <- unique(pb$data[[3]][,c("colour", "group")])
table2 <- merge(table, scale_cols, by.x = "N", by.y = "group", sort = FALSE)
table2$N2 <- "\u2015"
table2 <- table2[,c("N", "N2", "Prb FR", "Prb ED", "colour")]

# Define vectors of fills and colors for table
fills <- c(table2$colour, rep("grey90", nrow(table2)*4))
cols <- c(rep("black", nrow(table2)*1), table2$colour, rep("black", nrow(table2)*3))
bgcols <- c(rep("white", nrow(table2)*5))
tt <- ttheme_default(core=list(bg_params = list(fill=fills, col=bgcols), fg_params = list(col=cols)))
t <- tableGrob(table2, theme = tt, rows = NULL)

# Combine plot and table
grid.arrange(p, t[,c(1:4)], nrow = 1, ncol = 2, widths=c(2,0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Just very briefly skimmed over the code and +1 ; but would be nice to have a little pointer as to how this is different to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70581378/7941188

Comment: Thanks for the comment; I appreciate the feedback. I added a sentence to point out the difference. In your opinion, do you think some version of my answer would have been better as a comment on that answer? I'm still learning how to best contribute to the site.

Comment: I think as long as you point out the difference clear enough, then each voter can decide if it is worth an upvote or not for them.

Comment: some people write amazing answers only in comments, which is also sad, because comments can easily be deleted without any trace, and also it is less visible and cannot be "accepted"

Comment: It is not always easy to decide what to do best, even after a few years here :)

Comment: Got it - thanks for sharing your thoughts! Good luck out there