# Modify spacing between key glyphs in vertical legend whilst keeping key glyph border

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

As a follow up to [this famous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366964/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-spacing-between-legend-items-in-ggplot2). I decided to ask a new question because this is more specifically for vertical legends, and the given answers still don't provide a fully satisfactory solution. For polygon key glyphs, there was a suggestion to increase the size of the margin between the actual polygon glyph and the key border, [with a modification of the underlying draw_key function](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2844#issuecomment-414808742). However, this doesn't really work if I want to keep a border, e.g., in black.

And when using other geoms (e.g., geom_line), I don't even see how to increase the margin between glyph and border - on a brief glance at the draw_key function used in `ggplot2:::GeomLine` (it doesn't use an exported draw_key function), it is not clear to me where to modify this.

So, my question is if there is a way to change the actual space between the key glyphs that would allow to keep a border (e.g., color = "black"), and without increasing the glyph size.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(dplyr::filter(msleep, grepl("^C", order)), 
       aes(sleep_total, sleep_rem, color = order)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = TRUE) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(color = "black"))
p
```

Example plot: Key glyphs touching.
[image]

```r
p + theme(legend.key.height = unit(.5, "in"))
```

Example that would look as if the glyphs are more spaced if I'd remove the color, but I want the key glyphs in the same size as above, just space between them.
[image]

The underlying draw_key in GeomLine

```r
# ggplot2:::GeomLine$draw_key
#> ...
#> segmentsGrob(0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5, gp = gpar(col = alpha(data$colour %||% 
#>                                                          data$fill %||% "black", data$alpha), fill = alpha(params$arrow.fill %||% 
#>                                                                                                              data$colour %||% data$fill %||% "black", data$alpha), 
#>                                            lwd = (data$size %||% 0.5) * .pt, lty = data$linetype %||% 
#>                                              1, lineend = "butt"), arrow = params$arrow)
#> ...
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

P.S. This question arose on answering [this interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70511777/7941188)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to do this, but it is not very intuitive. It depends on the `byrow` setting in the legend guide, whether the legend spacing is respected or not (don't ask me why!).

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dplyr::filter(msleep, grepl("^C", order)), 
            aes(sleep_total, sleep_rem, color = order)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = TRUE) +
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(byrow = TRUE)
  ) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(color = "black"),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(1, "cm"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I've <strike>complained</strike> [raised the suggestion](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4352#issue-813905291) that this is unintuitive elsewhere.

If you want the title to be in a relatively normal position, you can use the following incantation to the theme function, wherein 11 pt is the default legend spacing:

```r
legend.title = element_text(
  margin = margin(
  b = -1 + grid::convertUnit(unit(11, "pt"), "cm", valueOnly = TRUE), 
  unit = "cm")
)
```

Comment: Teunbrand. thanks once more, and certainly not the last time :) I've updated Tung's answer in the linked thread accordingly, and closed this thread here as a duplicate. Happy new year